# DOS Batch: Getting partial file names

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, dos

I've got this little batch file I'm trying to write for a Windows 7 environment. It's supposed to go through a directory and echo the last four characters of the file names. So far I've got:

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL
for /r C:\Users\userName\Desktop\testFolder %%g in (*) do (
   Set fileName = %%~ng
   echo %fileName:~-4%
)
```

And all that is echoed out is "~-4" once for each file in testFolder. I can't figure out what's wrong, but then I'm not very well versed in batch files or dos. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you want to program specifically for windows 7, then consider powershell.

Comment: I should have clarified. It's not specifically for windows 7, that's just the OS I'm developing on. The file may also have to run on a Windows XP machine. Thanks though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Environment variable expansion occurs when the command is read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx), so your `%fileName:~-4%` is evaulated when the `for` is read, which is *before* the `Set` is performed.  Use delayed expansion.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL SETDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /r C:\Users\userName\Desktop\testFolder %%g in (*) do (
   Set fileName=%%~ng
   echo !fileName:~-4!
)
```

Note also that spaces are significant in the `Set` command. With the space, you created a variable called `fileName`  with a trailing space.